# Excel lookup special character

Tags: excel

I am looking up cell C2 in range A1:B9 and returning the value from 2nd column.

The cell value can be text or text and special characters eg. `CL,CL*,C-L` etc.

The range has space in front or after the characters so I guess trim required.

I used the below formula which include "~"& before and after C2 to let excel read the special character as they are. However it is not working as I expected. Can anyone point out the issue and solution?

```
=VLOOKUP("~"&C2&"~",TRIM($A$1:$B$9),2,FALSE)
```

---

i.e.

I am looking up `Cl*` (C2) and the range of lookup is like below, I expect the formula to return `Cl*` but it returns `ClG`:

```
 ClG            ClG             
 Cl*?           C?*         
 GlCl?          Gl?             
 Cl*            Cl*             
    GlCl        GlC             
    CataclyV*   CV*             
 Cloud          Cld             
 *inCl          *iC             
 GinCl          GiC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"?","~?"),"*","~*"),TRIM($A$1:$B$9),2,0)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

**UPDATE:**

similar to another answer, you can use this one *without array enrty* (returns last appearence of cell `C2` in range `A1:A9`):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(TRIM(A1:A9)=C2),B1:B9)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. Would you be able to confirm why it is not why the tilde is not working in my case to read the special character as I seen a lot of post provides solution as such similar to my case.

Comment: if your `C2` cell contains `Cl*`, you should use `Cl~*` for search, but your formula `"~"&C2&"~"` gives you `~Cl*~` which is not what you need:)

Comment: also, does it apply across all special characters? I see only ? and * is substituted

Comment: what another special characters you need? it right now it affects only `*` and `?`

Comment: I completely understand what you explained. however,if you dont mind, can you have a quick look of this 5 min shortcourse?(Really wanna know what makes the different) it is working in the case provided which is similar to mine

Comment: my actual lookup range is 2000+ row plus and i only pick a sample. I need more universal one can cover possible cases

Comment: can you show any example when my formula doesn't work? what universal case do you mean?

Comment: in your video there only _one_ special characters in the biggining or in the end, but you have strings like this: `Cl*?`

Comment: I tried few others and it works perfectly. The reason why i am asking is that i concern if any data not tested would have issue since it is not realistic to test all 2000 rows

Comment: @user3459594, for reliability you could also use `=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"?","~?"),"*","~*"),"~","~~"),TRIM($A$1:$B$9),2,0)` - it takes into account `~`, `*` and `?`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this array formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B9;MATCH(1;FIND(C2;TRIM(A1:A9));0))
```

You need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

Yes you are right replace by:

```
=INDEX(B1:B9;MATCH(1;1*(C2=TRIM(A1:A9));0))
```

Comment: somehow, it is returning C?* but not Cl*